# Lagrange inversion formula example unclear

Tags: complex-analysis

The following example is from De Bruijn's Asymptotic methods in analysis (page 24). The considered equation is

$x^t = e^{-x}$

The author wants to transform the equation into the form: $w=z/f(z)$, in order to use the Lagrange inversion formula. So he sets $x=1+z$ and $t^{-1}=w$. And then obtains the equation for $f(z)$ as: $f(z)=-z(1+z)/(\log{(1+z}))$. And then says:

> The function $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$: $f(z)=-1+c_1z+...$.
>
> It follows that $x=1-t^{-1}-c_1t^{-2}+...$

My question is: This function $f(z)$ at $z=0$ will be $0/0$. i.e. undefined! So how come he says the function is analytic at $z=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a removable singularity; we commonly identify functions with removable singularities with the function which agrees with them on the original domain and with the singularities removed. It's a removable singularity because the numerator and denominator are analytic in a neighborhood of $z=0$ and both scale as $O(z)$ as $z \to 0$.

Comment: But in this case shouldn't the writer define the new function's value at the points of singularity? He didn't mention what will be the value of $f$ at 0. And the use of the Lagrange inversion theorem depends on that value.

Comment: @Dorgham It's somewhat redundant to do so, because we almost always select the continuous extension, i.e. we define $f(0)$ to be $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$. That's what it means to "remove the singularities"; selecting a discontinuous extension leaves the singularities intact.